# Send range from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to send a range from Excel to Access Table.
The Excel range have 20 columns and the Access table have 20 fields in the good order
I used this code

```
adoConn.Execute "INSERT INTO  OPT  SELECT * FROM Range2Export"
```

`Range2Export` is defined as a Range with 20 columns.
`OPT` is my Access table

I get this Error: `The Microsoft Access Database Engine cannot find the input table or query 'Range2Export'.`

I used this help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819 but didn't  helped me.
If someone can help
Thank you

Comment: Is your `Range2Export` a named range or a worksheet? Is the Connection definitely valid and established?

Comment: Connection is valid, because I use it earlier in the macro and it works..... I have `Dim Range2Export As Range` and then `Set Range2Export = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow, 41))`

Comment: `Range2Export` is well defined... i tried to copy paste it to another sheet and it select the good cells

Comment: ah but it is not a `NamedRange` in the Excel file! Only in your VBA. So when you pass `Range2Export` as a query to Excel it has no idea what to do with that because you've defined that variable in your code not in the xlsx. You need to make Named Range out of it to select things like that.

Comment: I tried with the `Named Range` but not working...I tried as well to copy paste my range to a new sheet named Temp and used `adoConn.Execute "INSERT INTO  OPT  SELECT * FROM [Temp$]"`  but didnt work as well

Comment: Same error? Can you just do `Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset` `Set rst=adoConn.Execute "SELECT * FROM [Temp$]"`? Does that return records?

Comment: have a syntax error... vba expect an end of statement...

Comment: Oh sorry, you need parens around the Execute now that its return object is being set to a variable. `Set rst=adoConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [Temp$]")`

Comment: Have same error  `The Microsoft Access Database Engine cannot find the input table or query 'Temp$'.`

Comment: Have you tried using the `Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet` function?

Answer (score 0):

You want your `Range2Export` to exist within the context of your xlsx file. in order to do this you need to add it as a named range like so

```
Set Range2Export = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow, 41))
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Range2Export",Range2Export.Address
```

Comment: ty but does not export to Access ... still have the same error `The Microsoft Access Database Engine cannot find the input table or query 'Range2Export'.`